# getting selected radio button value

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am adding a radio button in a gridrow dynamically on rowdatabound event.
I want value of selected radio button of specific row of grid.

Currently I am getting value bt it will no return the value for specific row index.

See my below code:

```
function GetBlastid()
     {  
         var gv = document.getElementById("<%=grdOofMailProcess.ClientID%>");  
         var rbs = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");  
         var flag = 0;  
         for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++)
         {  
             if (rbs[i].type == "radio")
             {  
                 if (rbs[i].checked)
                 {  
                 alert(rbs[i]);
                     flag = 1;  
                     document.getElementById('hdnBlastId').value=rbs[i].value
                     break;  
                 }  
             }  
         }
     }
```

Comment: is jquery as a second option? if yes than try   ` var selValue = $('input[name=rbnNumber]:checked').val(); `

Answer (score 0):

well once you get which radiobox is checked navigate to its parent and get the row index row.rowIndex , i couldnt give you the exact code coz i dont know how you placed the radio button, whether its directly under a column or have a different parent.

```
function GetBlastid()
 {  
     var gv = document.getElementById("<%=grdOofMailProcess.ClientID%>");  
     var rbs = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");  
     var flag = 0;  
     for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++)
     {  
         if (rbs[i].type == "radio")
         {  
             if (rbs[i].checked)
             {  
             alert(rbs[i]);
//here get the parent of rbs[i] and navigate to the row to get the row index.
                 flag = 1;  
                 document.getElementById('hdnBlastId').value=rbs[i].value
                 break;  
             }  
         }  
     }
 }
```

Comment: i have added radio button dynamically.one grid row can have multiple radio button based on no of id retuns.

Comment: yep even when multiple radio buttons are available lets say <tr><td><inradio id=1><inradio id=2></td></tr> when radio button2 is checked, you can still get the parent which is td and then get parent of td which tr and get the rowIndex, let me know if that works